Has a telepath ever worn Juggernaut's helmet in the comics, blocking their powers from working?
Juggernaut's helmet is well-known for its ability to protect him from telepathic attacks, particularly those of Professor X. But I'm curious if it's ever been used in reverse—to block a telepath's powers from the inside out.
This question came to mind after watching

Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), where the heroes put Juggernaut's helmet on Cassandra Nova's head to neutralize her powers. As Professor X's twin, Cassandra possesses similar mental powers.

I'm wondering if the comics have ever explored a similar scenario. Has a telepath ever donned Juggernaut's helmet, rendering their powers useless? It's an interesting concept that flips the helmet's usual function on its head.
This query is similar to a previous question: If Charles Xavier wore Magneto's helmet, would it block Charles from using his abilities?. However, I'm specifically interested in instances involving Juggernaut's helmet in the comics.
